# Retrieving Data from MS Access using Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, ms-access, double

Okay so a little background. I found out that it was difficult to do a shared DLL in C#, and it really wasn't worth the trouble since this is just a school project that is pretty much done, and I'd rather go this route anyway.

So I put data in MS Access through this code.

```
     public void SetBal(double money)
    {
        bal = money; //balance equals whatever money that was sent to it
        string query = "Insert into Users" + "([Money])" + "Values (@Money)" + "where Users.UserID = 1";
        dbconn = new OleDbConnection(connection);
        OleDbCommand insert = new OleDbCommand(query, dbconn);
        insert.Parameters.Add("Money", OleDbType.Char).Value = bal;
        dbconn.Open();
        try
        {
            int count = insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (OleDbException ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            dbconn.Close();
        }

    }
```

Alright, that works. The problem is when I'm trying to retrieve data from the database.

```
    public double GetBal()
    {
        string query = "SELECT Users.Money FROM Users";
        bal = Convert.ToDouble(query);
        return bal;
    }
```

I can't convert the query result to a double. I don't know if the code is just wrong, or am I just going about it the wrong way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are casting string "SELECT Users.Money FROM Users" to double, not the result of the query. Do the same operations you did with update query, but execute reader to get all the values - http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/979byfca.aspx.

Comment: Thanks, I don't even see how I didn't realize that. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 2):

```
public double GetBal()
{
  // Make sure you change this to a real userID that you pass in.
  var query = "SELECT Users.Money FROM Users WHERE Users.UserID = 1";

  double balance = 0;

  using (var dbconn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString)) {
    var command = new OleDbCommand(query, dbconn);
    dbconn.Open();

    // Send the command (query) to the connection, creating an
    // OleDbReader in the process. We want it to close the database
    // connection in the process so we pass in that behavior as an
    // argument (CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
    var myReader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

    // this while loop will keep executing until there are no more rows
    // to read from the database. myReader.Read() moves to the next row
    // in the database too. The first read() puts you at the first row.
    while(myReader.Read()) 
    {
        // Use the reader's GetDouble() method to read the data and convert
        // it to a double. The 0 is there because it is the first column in
        // the results. for example to read the third column, it would be
        // myReader.GetDouble(2).
        balance = myReader.GetDouble(0));
    }
    // because there is only one row (query said where Users.UserID = 1) the
    // above loop will only execute once.

    // Close the reader so we can tell the command that the connection
    // can be closed...because CommandBehavior.CloseConnection was specified
    myReader.Close();
  }

  // return the value we got from the database
  return balance;
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response, I appreciate it a lot. I have a question. I understand everything up until after the try, and before the catch. Can you explain exactly what is going on. Thanks, I just want to understand the code a little better.

Comment: I added a bunch of comments and simplified it a bit. Hopefully this will help you understand it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create / open your connection and then execute the query.  You did it for the insert - now you need to create the same thing in your get method using a select query.  You need to execute the query and then cast the result of the query as a double.